# How to run a function when Alarm Manager finishes?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, alarmmanager

I want to run the function `foo()` when the alarm manager runs off, but I have not understood how do I do it. I saw you pass an Intent to the alarm manager, are there other ways to do that?

```
 public void SetAlarm()
 {
 Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
  cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 19);
cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 03);
  cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
 cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

    AlarmManager alarmMgr = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
     Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, 0);
      alarmMgr.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
}
```

As you can see, I'm not sure how to use the alarmMgr.set function correctly. Also, do I need to run it as a service, so if the application will be exited, then it'll still work ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I saw you pass an Intent to the alarm manager

You pass a `PendingIntent` to `AlarmManager`.

> are there other ways to do that?

The only way you can use `AlarmManager` is with a `PendingIntent`. The purpose of `AlarmManager` is to give your app control at points in time in the future when your app is no longer running.

> Also, do I need to run it as a service, so if the application will be exited, then it'll still work ?

No. The goal of `AlarmManager` specifically is to allow your process to be terminated, yet give you control again some time in the future, so you are not tying up memory all that time.

Comment: Thank you very much for the explaniation, but, How do I use it? if I want to run a specific function when the alarm goes off, how can I do it ?

Comment: If you're looking for an example which demostrates usage of `AlarmManager` take a look on this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459058/alarm-manager-example

Comment: @Amit: You do not "run a specific function when the alarm goes off". You either start an activity, send a command to a service, or send a broadcast. You need to choose which of those three options is what you want, then set up a `PendingIntent` for that operation. Where your code from `foo()` goes depends upon which of those three options you chose and other characteristics, such as whether you are using a `_WAKEUP`-style alarm. Using `AlarmManager` properly is rather complex (my book's chapter on it is ~30 pages) and beyond the scope of a single StackOverflow answer.

Comment: Thanks for the help guys! but I've edited my code to something similar to the examples, yet it does not work... Please check my main post, I have edited there.
@CommonsWare

Thanks!

Comment: You have already got the extensive answer for your question. For another question please open another topic.